# Python:How do I add another table if the remaining people is 6 or more than 6

Tags: python

- Calculate total tables based on the number of people.
- By default, each table can fit in only 10 people.
- Additional people can be added to the tables as long as it is less than 6 people

For example, if the number of people is 35 or 34 or 33 or 32 or 31, a total of 
3 tables are needed. If the number of people is 35, 36, 37, 38 or 39, 4 tables are needed.

Here's my code

```
def calculateTable(noofPeople)       

   totaltable= noofpeople/10
   int(round(totaltable))
   return totalTable
```

Comment: Try to explain better your problem. It lacks a proper introduction, so it is difficult to understand the purpose of your code. Also, there are syntax errors in the code, and the formatting is not correct. Finally, try to find your same problem in google or SO, as you will find it quite easily.

Comment: •Calculate total tables based on the number of people.
•By default, each table can fit in only 10 people.
•Additional people can be added to the tables as long as it is less than 6 people
•For example, if the number of people is 35 or less, a total of 3 tables are needed. If the number of people is more than 35, 4 tables is needed

Comment: @Stefan I'm reading it as 5 tables are enough - four tables of 15 and one of ten...

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, I wasn't optimizing, just doubling the situation. But now I think it's something like the restaurant has five extra chairs, that would explain an overall up to five extra people.

Comment: @user8885281 Your "code" still doesn't work at all. At least make it not crash.

Comment: As a "realistic" explanation, the rule means they don't reserve tables that will be less than half-full. But I'll bet the real reason is that "two extra guests _per table_" is just too hard for students tackling their first Python program.

Answer (score -1):

Two tips:

1. When you calculate something, save the result in a variable so you can use it later; and
2. to calculate the number of left-over people, find out how many people your tables can sit (at 10 people per table) and compare it to the number of guests.

More help than this would not help you solve the problem, but to avoid solving it.